Convert a Google Sheet to PDF file with formatting
I have been trying to convert a Google sheet to a PDF file. (This is the input Google Sheet.) I have browsed the internet and gotten to converting the Google Sheets to HTML using the gspread library, and converted that to a PDF using pdfkit. The script below works, but as intended, all formatting data of the sheets, including merged cells is lost.
import gspread
import pdfkit

wkhtmltopdf = r"wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=wkhtmltopdf)

gc = gspread.service_account()
sh = gc.open("Test")
sheet = sh.sheet1.get_all_values()

table = ""
for row in sheet:
    table += "<tr>"
    for data in row:
        table += f"<td>{data}</td>"
    table += "</tr>"

html = f'''
<html>
    <body>
    <table>
        {table}
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
'''

pdfkit.from_string(html, "test.pdf", configuration=config)

And this is the result.
I want that the merged cells remain merged, and the formatting should stay. From the gspread documentation I don't find any function to know which cells are merged, or to return the formatting.
Edit:
As @LimeHusky mentioned, I can use the colspan tag to merge the cells, but my concern is distinguishing between a normal cell and a merged one, and if it is merged, to what extent (No. of cells merged).
It's the same with other formats too.
For clarification, this is what the variable sheet returns.
[['ID00001', '', '', '', ''],
['', '', '', '', ''],
['Merged', '', '', '', ''],
['1', 'A', '10', '11', '70'],
['2', 'B', '20', '22', '80'],
['3', 'C', '30', '33', '70'],
['4', 'D', '40', '44', '90'],
['5', 'E', '50', '55', '70'],
['6', 'F', '60', '66', '100']]

Any solution that solves the problem would be appreciated.
Also, I am not specifically asking for a solution using HTML. I just need to convert the Google Sheet into a PDF file with all formatting, along with having control over which rows to render and which not to.

The problem is in the table the OP needs to add colspan to the merge string and add condition to get the exact value

Thanks @LimeHusky. I just realized I can use colspan to merge the cells, but this would only work if the sheet is static. I wanted to know how I can differentiate between a merged cell and a normal cell, and render the HTML accordingly.

@KJ, I do agree that using Excel would make the job much easier, but this is for a project that needs to specifically convert a Google Sheet into a PDF.

You can get a PDF blob by fetching the spreadsheet through a URL like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...id.../export?format=pdf. Replace ...id... with the spreadsheet ID. The PDF comes complete with merged cells and other formatting. Try the link in a browser to see how it looks like.

@doubleunary That's a great solution. it fulfills almost everything I needed. How come I didn't come across this before? Is there any documentation on these queries? The only thing wanted to know was whether you can add queries to the link to add line breaks. For example, If I want rows 1-2 in one page and rows 3-9 in the next page, how do I do it?

An exported PDF mirrors the layout of the spreadsheet, so put those rows in separate spreadsheet tabs to get them in separate PDF pages. Please ask only one question per post.

Python For Loop using Enumerate
I tried your Python code modified and added a condition, colspan and css text-align.
Modified code:
sheet = [
    ['ID00001', '', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', ''],
    ['Merged', '', '', '', ''],
    ['1', 'A', '10', '11', '70'],
    ['2', 'B', '20', '22', '80'],
    ['3', 'C', '30', '33', '70'],
    ['4', 'D', '40', '44', '90'],
    ['5', 'E', '50', '55', '70'],
    ['6', 'F', '60', '66', '100']
]


table = ""
for rowIndex, row in enumerate(sheet):
    table += "<tr>"
    if rowIndex == 0 or rowIndex == 2:  
        if row[0]:  
            table += f"<td colspan='5' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'>{row[0]}</td>"
    else:
        for data in row:
            if data:  # Skip empty cells
                table += f"<td>{data}</td>"
    table += "</tr>"

# Complete HTML structure
html = f'''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        table {{
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }}
        td {{
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {table}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
'''

Sample Output:

Reference:

Python - enumerate

Python - if condition


